# Create select based on specific column data - using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a table where in it has too many data and I want to put select option and just filter it, I already got the filter thing in the table  using select, my question is how can I not manually add options to the select?
for example I have a `column` of `dates` containing `5` - `01-12-19` , `2` - `01-13-19` and `10` - `01-14-19` the said dates need to be the one in the options, and should only display `3` dates which is `01-12-19`,`01-13-19`,`01-14-19`, the thing with manually adding options is not the best option because the column of dates are updated day by day.

```html
<select>
  <option></option>
</select>
<table border="2">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Dates</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>01-12-19</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jas</td>
      <td>01-12-19</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>sam</td>
      <td>01-12-19</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>James</td>
      <td>01-12-19</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>luke</td>
      <td>01-13-19</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>lucas</td>
      <td>01-13-19</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>laus</td>
      <td>01-13-19</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>cals</td>
      <td>01-13-19</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>miya</td>
      <td>01-14-19</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>lesley</td>
      <td>01-14-19</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I expect that using javascript the options will automatically fillout by the available dates but will only display in option as one even if there are 10 dates that are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're just trying to populate your `select` option with one of the columns then filter the below table every-time it changes, something like this will work.

```js
const table = document.getElementById('myTable');
const trs = table.querySelectorAll('tbody tr');
const getAllDatesInTable = () => {
  const table = document.getElementById('myTable');
  const trs = table.querySelectorAll('tbody tr');
  const dates = [];
  trs.forEach( tr => {
    const date = tr.querySelector('td:last-child').innerText;
    if (!dates.includes(date)) {
      dates.push(date);
    }
  });
  
  return dates;
};

const dates = getAllDatesInTable();
const select = document.getElementById('dateFilter');
select.innerHTML = dates.map( d => `<option value=${d}>${d}</option>`);
select.onchange = (e) => {
  const selection = e.target.value;
  
  trs.forEach( tr => {
    tr.style.display = '';
    const date = tr.querySelector('td:last-child').innerText;
    if (date !== selection) {
      tr.style.display = 'none';
    }
  });
};
```

```html
<select id="dateFilter">
  <option></option>
</select>
<table border="2" id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Dates</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>01-12-19</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jas</td>
      <td>01-12-19</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>sam</td>
      <td>01-12-19</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>James</td>
      <td>01-12-19</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>luke</td>
      <td>01-13-19</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>lucas</td>
      <td>01-13-19</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>laus</td>
      <td>01-13-19</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>cals</td>
      <td>01-13-19</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>miya</td>
      <td>01-14-19</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>lesley</td>
      <td>01-14-19</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for this one, I just have one more question, how can I add a reset option there? like to show all the data again.